# Using sp (spatial package) from my own package results in error: could not find function

Tags: r, r-sp, geosphere

I'm developing my first package - well, actually I'm packaging some existing code - in RStudio. I've marked up all the comments with roxygen2 and this has generated a correct NAMESPACE file which includes:

```
import(sp)
importFrom(geosphere,distMeeus)
importFrom(geosphere,distm)
```

I'm using the `distm()` function from the geosphere package to calculate a distance matrix but it is failing:

> Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : could not find function "is.projected" 
>   4 .pointsToMatrix(x) 
>   3 distm(OCC, SPAD, fun = distMeeus) at peta.R#79

now `is.projected()` is in the sp package, which I have imported so it should be in my search path. Shouldn't it?

As an experiment I just called `library(geosphere)` (which also loads sp) prior to calling my package code and my function got past that point. Soooo, do I still need to call `library()` for every package??? That seems a bit redundant and at this point I think I'll stop and see if someone can set me straight before I break anything further...

Comment: Have you added `IMPORTS: sp` to your `DESCRIPTION` file?

Comment: Hi @Andrie the DESCRIPTION file does have "Imports: ... sp, geosphere"

Comment: Moving `sp` from `Imports` to `Depends` works. I've been reading [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) but I can't actually figure out why this might be the case. I have a feeling it's to do with the difference between loading a package vs. attaching it, but the penny hasn't yet dropped for me.

Comment: Try the following:  Add `methods` to your Imports, i.e. `Imports: methods` as well as to your NAMESPACE, i.e. `import(methods)`. I know this sounds random, but if it works I'll do my best to explain why.

Comment: @Andrie Umm, no actually it didn't work. Bizarre that it worked for me yesterday after I added `methods` to `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`. Maybe sp was still `attach`ed??? (Even though the R session is restarted after every `Build & Reload`.) I tried to run it today after the computer's been shut down and got the same error. So I've had to put `sp` back in `Depends:` (which mirrors the configuration of `geosphere`).

Comment: Do you have this package on github (or other public repo) so we can take a look?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Currently working with our legal team to get it released under an open source licence. If you like I can code up a "minimum working example" as it seems to be quite reproducible. I think the fact that `geosphere` has `sp` in `Depends` is a big clue as to what's going on. I've e-mailed that package maintainer so hopefully he'll be able to shed some light...

Comment: Hi.  I think there is a general problem here.  I've seen the same (or similar) issue in a different set of packages.  If you are prepared to make a minimal example and put it on github, I promise to add a bounty to this question to attract some attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

I don't understand why this is, but you need to add `methods` to your package imports:

- Add to your `DESCRIPTION`:

  ```
  Imports: methods
  ```
- Add to your NAMESPACE:

  ```
  import(methods)
  ```

Comment: I downloaded the source package for geosphere and had a poke around. There is no `is.projected()` defined in that package, although that function is called six times.
Looking at the `DESCRIPTION` I found:
`Depends: sp, R (>= 2.10.0)
Suggests: methods, raster`
The `NAMESPACE` for that package contains:
`importFrom("sp", SpatialPolygons, SpatialLines)`

Comment: @MichaelHenry Thank you for checking.  Let me remove this bit of my answer.